# Spring: Is this pattern thread-safe?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, web-applications, thread-safety

I've been learning how to use the Spring framework for hibernate transaction management, and so far it has been a great help for that purpose. The problem is that recently, I realized that I hadn't been giving much thought to how the pattern that I chose handles concurrency, specially in the case of a web application.

Below is the code that exemplifies the pattern that I'm using, which is a combination of some examples I found, and a custom servlet implementation. I have a few doubts about how this pattern works and whether it is thread-safe since I customized it a bit. Some of my concerns are:

- Even though servlets are technically not singletons, I'm under the impression that most of the time there will be only a single instance for each servlet class.
- If I understand correctly, each auto-wired property will be a singleton, so if the above its true, then there'll be a single servlet instance with a single service instance, which in turn has a single DAO instance, which has its own SessionFactory instance.
- If the above is correct then I can imagine that every request on the servlet will be using the same objects and I wonder whether this is a good thing. After giving it some thought I can't tell whether it would be better for thread-safety to have singletons or to have new instances created for each http request.
- Usually these spring patterns have a @Controller class which I skipped in favor of our custom servlet and I'm wondering whether that could break the concurrency of the pattern somehow.

Thanks

```
public interface UserDAO
{
    public void save(User user);
}

@Repository
public class HibernateUserDAO implements UserDAO
{
    @Autowired(required=true)
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(User user)
    {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }
}

public interface UserService
{
    public void saveUser(User user);
}

@Service
public class DefaultUserService implements UserService
{
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(User user)
    {
        this.userDAO.save(user);
    }
}

public class UserServlet extends CustomServlet
{   
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private UserService userService;

    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        super.init();
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //would call the appropriate method depending on parameters, etc.
        //simplified here for demonstration purposes
        this.userService.saveUser(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a  specific question here. As it is, this looks like a request for a code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a suitable strategy set up in the Hibernate configuration, then `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` will return a *scoped* session, not a global one. Session factories are intended to be singletons, that's quite correct; `getCurrentSession()` is the usual method to bridge to the current context scope.

"suitable strategy" varies, but if you're using the spring transaction management wrapped around your DAO, then a session will have a lifetime of a DAO method call, and Spring will orchestrate calling commit/rollback as appropriate on exit.

Comment: Thanks. So this pattern is fine as long as I follow what Meriton said and I stick to spring transaction management?

Answer (score 3):

Spring beans are by default in application scope, i.e. there will only be a single instance in your application. You could change this with @Scope, but the typical pattern is to keep them in application scope and make them thread safe by not storing any state in the beans, i.e. all fields of application scoped beans should not be changed, or refer to objects that are changed, after the application has started.